# Redis share session with two different web application

Tags: java, spring-security, redis, spring-session, spring-oauth2

I have set up two web applications. they both using spring boot and spring security. these two applications connected to the same redis server.

The first application is used for login with google OAuth. The second application is used for business operation.

These two applications have the same domains but different sub domain.

My purpose is login through the application 1 and store the session in redis then across application 2 by check the session in redis is exist or not.

Is Redis support to share the session between two different we b application? If not, any other methods so that i can achieve my goal?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi web applications connect to Redis server, and write or read data.
So yo can share the session between two different web application.

But I recommended, each Redis should only connected by one Application, and the application can offer many apis for other apps who want to get data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with help of "spring session". The idea is to configure web application to store session outside server and share it with other application. It supports redis out of the box. Read here for more information,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html#boot-how